# How to substitute alternate positions in a string using awk

Tags: html, shell, awk, substring

I have a lookup file that I use to search the available records in file_2 and if such records are present then replace those records with #. Currently my code is substituting the entire record with # but I need to partially substitute it.
I want to replace every two characters of the string with #. How can I do so? Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

**code**

```
awk ' NR==FNR {
s = $0;
gsub("[A-Za-z0-9]","#");
a[s] = $0;
next
}

{
if match($0, ">[^<]+"))
{
str = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)
if (str in a )
{
$0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART) a[str] substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
}
lines[FNR]=$0
}

END {for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++)
{
for (str in a )
{
regex = "\\<" str "\\>"
gsub(regex,a[str],lines[I])
}
}' lookup file_1 > file_2
```

**cat lookup**

```
CDX98XSD
@vanti Finserv Co.
11:11 - Capital
MS&CO(NY)
MS&CO(NY)
MS&CO(NY)
```

**cat file_1**

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">Records</span><table>
<tr class="data">
<td>@vanti Finserv Co.</td>
<td>11:11 - Capital</td>
<td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>CDX98XSD</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td>@vanti Finserv Co.</td>
<td></td>
<td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
<td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
<td></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

****expected output****

```
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">Records</span><table>
<tr class="data">
<td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
<td>1##11 - C##I##l</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>C##9##S#</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
<td></td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- duplicate entries in `lookup` can be ignored (ie, we don't treat duplicate occurrences differently)
- for each white space delimited string in `lookup` we want to replace the nth/(n+1)th characters with `#` (where `n` = 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,....)
- for the `lookup` string `11:11 - Capital` the correct replacement string is `1##1# - C##i##l` (as opposed to OP's `1##11 - C##i##l`)

Added following lines to input files (based on comment from OP):

```
# file: lookup
READ 1234
READ
READ NOW

# file: file_1
<td>READ 1234 stuff READ</td>
<td>READ READ NOW</td>
<td>READ NOW READ 9999 York</td>
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { if ($0 in lookups)                           # if duplicate then ...
             next                                      # ignore
          lookups[$0]=$0
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                        # loop through list of white space delimited fields
              oldstr=$i
              newstr=""
              while (oldstr) {                         # while oldstr != ""
                    len=length(oldstr)
                    # keep 1st char; replace 2nd/3rd chars if length > 1/2, respectively
                    newstr=newstr substr(oldstr,1,1) substr("##",1,len-1)
                    oldstr=substr(oldstr,4)            # strip off first 3 characters
              }
              ndx=index(lookups[$0],$i)                # locate position of $i in current line
              # replace $i with newstr
              lookups[$0]=substr(lookups[$0],1,ndx-1) newstr substr(lookups[$0],ndx+length($i))
          }
          next
        }

        { match_found=1
          while (match_found) {

                match_found=0
                ndx=99999999
                len=0
                n=99999999

                # find earliest and longest match

                for (i in lookups) {

                    curr_len=length(lookups[i])
                    curr_ndx=index($0,i)

                    if (curr_ndx > 0) {
                       match_found=1

                       if (curr_ndx < ndx || (curr_ndx == ndx && curr_len > len)) {
                          ndx=curr_ndx
                          len=curr_len
                          n=i
                       }
                    } # if (curr_ndx > 0)
                } # for (i in lookup)

                if (match_found)
                   $0=substr($0,1,ndx-1) lookups[n] substr($0,ndx+len)

          } # while ( match_found )
          print
        }

 # uncomment following block to display contents of lookups[]
 #END    { print "############ lookups[]"
 #         for (i in lookups)
 #             print i " => " lookups[i]
 #         print "############"
 #       }
' lookup file_1 > file_2
```

This generates:

```
$ cat file_2
<html>
<body>
<hr><br><>span class="table">Records</span><table>
<tr class="data">
<td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
<td>1##1# - C##i##l</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>C##9##S#</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="data">
<td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
<td></td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td>M##C##N##</td>
<td></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<td>R##D 1##4 stuff R##D</td>
<td>R##D R##D N##</td>
<td>R##D N## R##D 9999 York</td>
```

Focusing on just the differences:

```
$ diff file_1 file_2
5,7c5,7
< <td>@vanti Finserv Co.</td>
< <td>11:11 - Capital</td>
< <td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
---
> <td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
> <td>1##1# - C##i##l</td>
> <td>M##C##N##</td>
9c9
< <td>CDX98XSD</td>
---
> <td>C##9##S#</td>
16c16
< <td>@vanti Finserv Co.</td>
---
> <td>@##n## F##s##v C##</td>
18c18
< <td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
---
> <td>M##C##N##</td>
21,22c21,22
< <td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
< <td>MS&CO(NY)</td>
---
> <td>M##C##N##</td>
> <td>M##C##N##</td>
27,29c27,29
< <td>READ 1234 stuff READ</td>
< <td>READ READ NOW</td>
< <td>READ NOW READ 9999 York</td>
---
> <td>R##D 1##4 stuff R##D</td>
> <td>R##D R##D N##</td>
> <td>R##D N## R##D 9999 York</td>
```

Uncommenting the `END{...}` block generates:

```
############ lookups[]
READ NOW => R##D N##
READ => R##D
MS&CO(NY) => M##C##N##
READ 1234 => R##D 1##4
CDX98XSD => C##9##S#
@vanti Finserv Co. => @##n## F##s##v C##
11:11 - Capital => 1##1# - C##i##l
############
```

Comment: Hi Markp-fuso, i seem to have encountered a bug in your code. This code seems to be failing for records with partly similar words, eg - READ , READ NOW , READ 1234. Above logic only masks the first instance of READ and ignores others. Awk arrays are not ordered hence its possible that the for loop processes the entry for READ before it processes READ NOW; as a result a line containing READ NOW matches READ and is changed to R##D NOW, and subsequently when the loop tries READ NOW that does NOT match so the line isn't further changed. Can you please help me fix it.

Comment: Awaiting your response! @markp-fuso

Comment: a bit verbose but I've modified to apply all lookups while looking for the earliest and longest match in a line; testing shows it still works for the original data as well as: `lookup: READ 1234 \n READ \n READ NOW` and `file_1: <td>READ 1234 stuff READ</td> \n <td>READ READ NOW</td> \n <td>READ NOW READ 9999 York</td>`; if you find new issues with different inputs I'd recommend you try to modify the current code and if unable to address the new data then ask a new question making sure to provide sample data and the modified code